# The code "should" work, but the program stops working

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm a beginner with a few hours of expirience and I'm trying to make a really simple program to get familiar withe IF command. I came up with this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char ans;
    char n;
    char y;
    printf("Do you want to exit?\n");
    scanf("%c\n",ans);
    if (ans == y)
    {
        printf("As you wish!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else (ans == n);
    {
        printf("You'll exit anyways!\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I think it should work, but after I type something the program stops workig! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `n` and `y` are never set to an actual value - if you'd like to compare them against `ans`, you'll need to do something like `char n = 'n';`

Comment: `if` is not a command, it's a statement. C has no "commands".

Comment: `scanf("%c\n",&ans);`

Comment: I fixed it but there is one more problem: I have to type my choice twice, or else it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
else (ans == n);
```

This doesn't give expected results. Remove the `;` and the condition.
`else` may only take a body of code. It does not handle conditions.
If you want conditions, use `else if`:

```
else if (ans == 'n')
```

More errors:

```
if (ans == y)
```

y in here refers to the variable, which is declared but has no value. Surely you want to refer to the character `'y'`:

```
if (ans == 'y')
```

Also, `scanf` expects a pointer, so instead of `ans`, use `&ans`.
It needs to write to the memory address of the value. It doesn't care about the value.
You'll learn about pointers eventually. (Assuming you haven't gone over them in your few hours of experience)

Comment: "This doesn't compile." -> Why?

Comment: @Magtheridon96: `;` is a valid statement. This is not what the OP wanted to write, but it is *correct C*.

Comment: Oh! Right. I see the obscureness here.

Answer (score 9):

The

```
if (ans == y)
```

should read

```
if (ans == 'y')
```

The former compares `ans` to the value of the uninitialized variable `y`, whereas the latter checks whether `ans` contains the character `'y'`.

The same goes for `'n'`.

The `y` and `n` variables are unnecessary and can be removed.

Also, the following line is incorrect:

```
else (ans == n);
```

It should read

```
else if (ans == 'n')
```

(I've added the `if` and have removed the semicolon.)

Finally, the `scanf()` should read:

```
scanf("%c",&ans);
```

Comment: `else (ans == 'n');` is syntactically valid; it just parses differently than what OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

There are three main errors.

- You should pass *pointers* to the `scanf` function, so you have to add an ampersand before `ans` (`&ans`).
- There is a trailing `;` at the end of the `else` statement.
- `y` refers to a variable (which does not exist), whereas you want to compare `ans` against the *character* `'y'`.